# Backbone, multi-language and root

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, localization

I'm using backbone to manage my routing. I need to implement multi-language on my website as following :

- in french : www.example.com
- in english : www.example.com/en

Moreover I have an additional root on my url on production, so it gives www.example.com/dev or www.example.com/dev/en

The root is provided through my web server (node). It's retrieved through the <%- prefix %> variable in the example below.

It works well on localhost, but as soon as I pass on my server with a url with the additional root, the pages are not found. I'm looking for a generic solution to manage both situations (with or without root).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{    
    let prefix = '<%- prefix %>'.substr(1);

    var BaseRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({    
        routes: {

            [prefix + 'imgfocus/:imgid'] : 'imgfocus',
            [prefix + 'skymap/:obsids'] : 'skymap',
            // ...
            },

        imgfocus : function(imgid)
        {
            navservice.loadScreen({page : 'imgfocus', imgid : imgid});
        },
        skymap : function(obsids, stateid, tourid)
        {
            navservice.loadScreen({page : 'skymap', obsids : parseInt(obsids) === 0 ? undefined : obsids, stateid : stateid, tourid : tourid});
        },
        /// ...
    });


    let br = new BaseRouter();

    for (let i = 0; i < navservice.languages.length; i++)
        {
            if (navservice.languages[i] !== '')
            {
                for (let key in br.routes)
                {
                    br.routes[navservice.formatUrl(key, navservice.languages[i]).substr(1)] = br.routes[key];
                }
            }
        }
        // language retrieval
        var language = navservice.getUserLanguage();

        Backbone.history.start({pushState : true, root: '/' + (language ? language : '')});
    }

    $(document).on("click", "a:not([data-bypass])", function (evt) {
        var href = { prop: $(this).prop("href"), attr: $(this).attr("href") };
        var root = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + Backbone.history.options.root;
        if (href.prop && href.prop.slice(0, root.length) === root) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var route = href.attr;

            // language retrieval
            var lang = navservice.getUserLanguage(route);

            if(lang && route.slice(0,lang.length+1) === "/" + lang) {
                route = route.slice(lang.length+1);
            }

            Backbone.history.navigate(route, {trigger : true});
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to fix it by adding log inside backbone.js and checking what was going on.

The real issue was in the usage of 'prefix' variable in the routes definition. I removed it and most of the fix was done.

Comment: Do you know why it was causing problem?

Comment: Actually I didn't really understood how the "root" variable was working. And this was the issue. As far as I understood, the url is managed as following : [domain name] + [root] + [route]. So I simply removed the "prefix" from my code and put it into the root. And this is it !

Answer (score 0):

Create differents templates, then use `history root` option:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/en/"})
```

More info [backbone history start](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start).